# fontconfig/fontconfig.h not found in Codeblocks

Tags: cocos2d-x, codeblocks

I am trying to build **Cocos2d-x** project in Codeblocks IDE in Ubuntu 14. I got `fontconfig/fontconfig.h` not found error during compiling. I'm stuck here. How can I solve this?

Comment: Same error appeared when installing `install.packages("httpgd")` in R

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem is that you are missing the package `libfontconfig1-dev`. From the command line run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1-dev
```

Or else use Software Centre and search for the package, if you prefer the graphical approach.